# Are The Bravest Warriors and Adventure Time related?

Tags: adventure-time

I have noticed that in both Adventure Time and The Bravest Warriors they both have very similar characters that look very similar in appearance and have settings with very similar or the same voices that play the characters in Adventure Time and The Bravest Warriors?

Is this just me or a coincidence and was this done on purpose?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: They have the same creator: Pendleton Ward.

Comment: I've heard rumor that Bravest Warriors is in the same universe, but I have no idea where that rumor came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can gather (having not seen the show) Bravest Warriors is set in 3085. The oldest inhabitants of Ooo in Adventure Time are Marceline and Simon, and Marceline is 1003 years of age. ( `Her age was the answer to one of Gaia Online's ten trivia contests to answer to try to win a first season DVD set.` --[Adventure time wiki](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Marceline#Appearances_in_other_media))

This I believe puts the time line of Ooo to be ~995 years from present day give or take.

This would mean that Adventure Time is set around 3009 leaving 76 years between the two series, which seems perfectly cromulant.

The only last thing is that in Bravest Warriors I believe they can cross dimensions and time travel . So even if the two settings re not the same, it's not beyond the creators ability to mix the two with some light hand waving.

Comment: There's also the shots of what looks like the Earth in Bravest Warriors where Chris sees images of the future and sees a planet with a large chunk missing from the it which resembles Earth.  In an episode of Adventure Time you see that there is a large chunk of the planet missing from what's assumed to be The Great Mushroom War.

Comment: http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2013/057/3/c/bravest_warriors_and_adventure_time_earth_by_gracklewing-d5wcugg.png

Comment: "Bravest warriors is set in 3085, and the oldest inhabitants are Marceline and Simon" -- Is this saying that Marceline and Simon have appeared on the show Bravest Warriors in addition to their regular appearances on Adventure Time, or is it just switching from talking about Bravest Warriors to talking about Adventure Time? If they did appear on Bravest Warriors can someone give an episode reference?

Comment: @hypnosifl to my knowledge they've not been in Bravest Warriors

Comment: OK thanks, I edited that part slightly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Beth actually dreams of adventure time in her dream, she sees ooo and the candy kingdom. It's hard to tell but we can clearly see the ice kingdom in the corner. (See vol 3 bravest warriors)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to adventure time wiki and read the article about the great mushroom wars, it seems that bravest warriors takes place before adventure time because in bravest warriors there is a scene in which shows earth with a small chunk of it missing and in adventure time there is a scene showing earth with a much bigger chunk missing. This might show that bravest warriors and adventure time are related. Click on this link to read the article: http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Mushroom_War